# How to convert audio to video with VLC?

Tags: audio, video, conversion, vlc-media-player

I'm familiar with the use of VLC to transcode videos, or to extract audio from video. What I'd like to do is the reverse of that. I have a very long MP3 and would like to generate a  simple video track for it — maybe visualizer, or a slide show, or even just a static picture — and save the result for use on another video player. I can't figure out how to do this. All of the search results for "vlc convert audio to video" are guides to convert video to audio.

To illustrate: this command line displays the audio/video combination that I want:

```
vlc verylong.mp3 --audio-visual=visual --effect-list=vuMeter
```

But when I run this command line to save it:

```
vlc verylong.mp3 --audio-visual=visual --effect-list=vuMeter --sout='#transcode{vcodec=mpgv,audiosync}:std{access=file,mux=ps,dst=verylong.mpg}'
```

Only the audio track is saved in verylong.mpg.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or should I try another tool (e.g. ffmpeg)?

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?

Comment: Yes, I don't recall anymore exactly what I did but it involved making a slide show.

Comment: That is to say, the visualizer and static-image paths both went nowhere. I ended up making a slide show of one image.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Microsoft Windows platform, I recommend you to use Movie Maker Software. It's neat and easy. Best part - It's free! Download it [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-live/movie-maker).